# Ubuntu 16.04 is freezes after 5 mins

Tags: 16.04, kernel

We installed deeplearning framework (openface/python) on my laptop. after using it for 5 mins my laptop is getting stuck.

I tried adding a boot parameter to fix it ([How do I add a kernel boot parameter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter)), but the issue is not resolved.

kernel version: 4.4.0-31-generic
laptop: Asus R558UQ Core i5 7th Generation

Comment: It is getting into HUNG state only if i open **openface** file(.py). while all other browsing activities it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The laptop **Asus R558UQ** demands few drivers (available in CD while purchase) need to be installed  prior installing ubuntu. In my case i directly installed ubuntu without installing drivers. Due to which it was going to hung state.

Thanks
ASH